# OAuth2 client that works on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

Can anyone advice me on a good library or else how to go about having a Python appengine based application using OAuth to authenticate to another server?

I have an application on appengine that expects user input. I would like the user to be able to upload an image, which I would put in *imgur.com* and would be able to show to the user back on my page. To be able to do that, I need to be able to authenticate to api.imgur.com hence the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/example/appengine_oauth.py) project.

A Client example:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

# Create your consumer with the proper key/secret.
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="your-twitter-consumer-key", 
    secret="your-twitter-consumer-secret")

# Request token URL for Twitter.
request_token_url = "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

# Create our client.
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

# The OAuth Client request works just like httplib2 for the most part.
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
print resp
print content
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplegeo oauth2 does not play well with GAE. Mike Knapp's library on [GitHub](https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library) is nice and simple, no install needed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use imgur-api, http://code.google.com/p/imgur-api/wiki/ImageUploading

Comment: I am afraid that is the old imgur API, before version 2. I would rather use the new one, hence OAuth.